# jQuery Progress Bar Animation When Scroll Point Less Than a Certain Number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make my progress bar animate when the container box reaches a certain scroll point on the screen.

````
let targetPosition = target.getBoundingClientRect();

var getStarted = setInterval(loading, 1);

function loading() {
  if (targetPosition.Top < 50) {
    $(".skill-bar").each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var per = $this.attr("per");
      $this.css("width", per + "%");
      $({ animatedValue: 0 }).animate(
        { animatedValue: per },
        {
          duration: 2000,
          step: function () {
            $this.attr("per", Math.floor(this.animatedValue) + "%");
          },
          complete: function () {
            $this.attr("per", Math.floor(this.animatedValue) + "%");
          },
        }
      );
    });
  }
}```
````

Comment: What happens when you run your current script? And how is it different from the behavior you want to see?

Comment: your code doesn't work, what does it actually means? check whether your js file loaded successfully or not